# Alexa Skill Custom slots - Currency

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Created a Custom Slot Type
**`CURRENCIES`** 
with values

```
USD
JPY
CNY
SGD
HKD
CAD
NZD
AUD
CLP
GBP
DKK
SEK
ISK
CHF
BRL
EUR
RUB
PLN
THB
KRW
TWD
```

tested successfully with Value INR, GBP, EUR.

> However during Certification got feedback
>
> When attempting to invoke the skill using an example present in the
>   example phrases or the skill’s description, the skill returns a non-
>   contextualized response or error. All customer facing example phrases
>   must function without error since these are interactions that users
>   are most likely to try.
>
> Steps To Reproduce: [Second Example Phrase]
>
> User: "Alexa, ask **XXX** to convert bitcoin to i n. r."
>
> Skill: "I didn't quite get that. Please provide currency to get
>   bitcoin value?"
>
> Please see test case 3.1 from our Submission Checklist for guidance on
>   example phrases.

When I run test case with `i n. r.` it fails.

How to map i n. r. with INR? Similar examples given in certification report g b. r. , e u. r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this. Any other solutions?

```
var tmp= this.event.request.intent.slots.CURRENCY_TO.value;
     if(tmp){
        var curr= tmp.toUpperCase().replace(/[\W_]/g, "");
```

Custom Slots validations needs to be handle in code. 
Reference - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/handle-requests-sent-by-alexa.html#input-errors